# ISharpText for converting html content to pdf

Tags: c#

I have a td tag with

```
<td bcolor="#000"></td>
```

but when i convert it into pdf from html content using Xmlworker I am unable to apply bhcolor to cell

Comment: Showing us some code on how you are converting to the pdf would help!

Comment: Better safe than sorry, so can you confirm that the `bcolor` in the question is a typo and that in the real code you're using `bgcolor`.

Comment: Possible related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178623/not-applying-the-css-while-generating-pdf-using-itextsharp-dll

Comment: Thanks everyone for that I was able to apply background color to td cell for tag during conversion from html to pdf when I replaced bgcolor with background-color