# iTextSharp 5.4.2 : Fixing the width of a column in a table

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I am using following code to generate PDF doc using iTextSharp library version 5.4.2.

```
// Create a Document object
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

        // Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        // Open the Document for writing
        document.Open();



    //Gets System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table
    //Returns HTML table with 4 coulms

        var flowsheetTable = GetTable(report);


        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            flowsheetTable.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        }


        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringWriter.ToString()), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }


        document.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt-test.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

The method GetTable() returns a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table which is having 4 columns. **Is there any way to fix the width of first column in the table. I want first column to take 40% of total width.**

Thank you

Comment: stylesheet is not working in html to pdf like(width).can you provide  html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're looping through the collection of `IElement` objects you can individual cast, inspect and modify each one. In your case you might want to do something like this:

```
//Sample table with four columns
var sampleTable = "<table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr></table>";

//Parse sample HTML to collection if IElement objects
List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(sampleTable), null);

//Declare variables for use below
IElement ele;
PdfPTable t;

//Loop through the collection
for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++) {

    //Get the individual item (no cast should be needed)
    ele = htmlarraylist[k];

    //If the item is a PdfPTable
    if (ele is PdfPTable) {

        //Get and cast it
        t = ele as PdfPTable;

        //Set the widths (40%/20%/20%/20%)
        t.SetWidths(new float[] { 4, 2, 2, 2 });

    }

    //Regardless of what was done above, add the object to our document
    document.Add(ele);
}
```

Comment: Thank you your reply. Is there any way to use CSS class as well. What I know is we need to apply CSS class on individual tags. So if I apply some style on a <p> tag, all the <p> tags will use the same style. Is there any way to apply style on individual rows/columns.

Comment: See this for using stylesheets with `HTMLWorker` http://stackoverflow.com/a/5322787/231316. Also, `HTMLWorker` is deprecated in favor of `XMLWorker`. You are highly encouraged to use the newer classes as that is where all active development is being focused.

Comment: Thank you quick reply. I did actually came across this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321779/itextsharp-css-not-getting-applied-c-sharp-net/5322787#5322787 earlier but they apply styling to individual tags. so if I apply some style to <H1> tag, same style will be applied to all the tags, I am looking for a way using which if a element for a style, then only it should be applied

Comment: The above links are per-tag rules so `H1` will be processed differently than `P`. But you can also use CSS classes, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184565/231316