# CSS style is not taken while generating pdf from html using itext

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

I can successfully generate a pdf from an html string, but the problem is that it doesn't take the css script. How can I generate the pdf with css style?
Please help! I have tried cssresolver als

My code is here:

```
{String result = "failed";

try 
{
String html2 ="<html>"+.....+"</html>" ;
  long timemilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String filename = "EastAfriPack2014_Ticket_"+timemilli;
           String writePath = Global.PDF_SAVE_PATH + filename ; 
           System.out.println("----------writePath--------------"+ writePath);

            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(writePath+".pdf"));
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());

            CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);  
            cssResolver.addCss("table {color: red;  background-color: blue; } ", true);

            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
            document.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("pdf created");
            result = filename;
            return filename;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link][1]. This might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178623/not-applying-the-css-while-generating-pdf-using-itextsharp-dll

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your approach works. I tried it before because, its the easiest way to create a PDF from HTML, but got bitten by same problem.

You either provide the styles inline via style attribute for the table

or

use the HTML, CSS files separately and send them to the HelperClass

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, 
                    new FileInputStream("myhtmlFile.html"), 
                    new FileInputStream("myCSSFile.css"));
```

the HTML part can also be an inputStream you made above in the code.