# How to use CSS proprieties in iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, .net, itext

How can I use CSS properties such as padding, cell-spacing, background color, etc... in iTextSharp?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `PdfPTable`

```
PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(2);   //Create table with 2 Cols
headerTbl.SetWidths(new float[] { 4, 1 });    //1st having size of 4 and other 1
headerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;   //Total Width of the table
headerTbl.SpacingBefore = 20f;
headerTbl.SpacingAfter = 30f;
```

You can Create Cells inside `PdfPTable`
Using this

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell
cell.Colspan = 3;                  //Colspan
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right  Horizontal alignment
```

**References**

1. http://jwcooney.com/2013/08/23/itextsharp-pdfptable-basic-example/
2. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/86/itextsharp-introducing-tables
3. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/89/itextsharp-page-layout-with-columns

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Java examples available that explain how to use XML Worker and CSS: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker

Some of these examples were written in answer to StackOverflow questions about iTextSharp:

- [How to get particular html table contents to write it in pdf using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530852/how-to-get-particular-html-table-contents-to-write-it-in-pdf-using-itext) (See [ParseHtmlTable1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable1) and [ParseHtmlTable2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable2) for a table with padding defined for `th` and `td` tags.)
- [Element inside class CSS definition not applied using ITextSharp (5.5.1) XHTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660890/element-inside-class-css-definition-not-applied-using-itextsharp-xhtml-to-pdf) (See [ParseHtmlTable3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable3) for an example where we define a green border in CSS.)
- [RowSpan does not work in iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679003/rowspan-does-not-work-in-itextsharp) (See [ParseHtmlTable4](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable4) for an example where we define a rowspan and a colspan, including a background color for cells.)
- [how can I add cellspacing to pdftable when parsing html using XMLWorker and itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698532/how-can-i-add-cellspacing-to-pdftable-when-parsing-html-using-xmlworker-and-itex) (See [ParseHtmlTable5](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable5) for an example where we use CSS to define a border-spacing and a padding.)

In a way, your question is not eligible for StackOverflow because it is too broad (you don't show what you've tried) and it is a duplicate of other questions.

Please make sure that you consult the official documentation, as well StackOverflow questions that have been answered (and accepted) in the past before creating a new question.

Comment: I want to use Margin , padding , position of a text